# Can RAMPS 1.4 be used for a 3D printer?

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I am making a DIY 3D printer on a budget. So, I came across a kit with RAMPS 1.4 with an Arduino Uno which is really a great price. But, I don't know if the RAMPS board and the stepper driver (DRV8825) which it supplies, can be used to make a 3D printer. And also will it come with average quality parts as the total amount of that kit is 2999 rupees or 40 dollars. Here is a picture if needed:

[image: Kit picture]

Comment: RAMPS was made specifically for 3D printers and those stepper drivers were used often in 3D printers. Have you searched online?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, yes, RAMPS 1.4 can be used for a 3D printer, but note that it is an outdated platform.

**But...**

From the supplied image can be concluded that the seller doesn't have a clue what is being sold in the webshop ( e.g. incorrect naming for the shield, 3 stepper motors and 4 stepper drivers?!?).

This is **not** a RAMPS set (RAMPS is a shield for an Arduino Mega 2560) but a CNC shield set. An Arduino Uno isn't typically the hardware used for a 3D printer (better suited for laser cutter), but you could use it. Also RAMPS itself is already outdated, there are other options for a bit more money.

---

*With a limited budget and limiting the time and frustration spent on building your own first printer from scratch it might be more economical to buy a 3D printer kit; a kit has all the parts for frame and electronics to get started relatively quick. These kits are documented, have upgrades and have proven to work and can be used to build a better 3D printer (that is exactly what I did). Note that building a printer yourself is usually not more economical, large kit manufacturers have discounts on buying parts in bulk which you don't have. Unless you are building a printer from wood/MDF and have a lot of parts readily available a kit may be a more economical solution.*

Comment: Trying to build 3d printer, before buying parts, the buyer should first spend amount of time reading, inspecting blueprints and detailed descriptions available online. For at least one complete 3d printer (probably FDM-type). There is number of different approaches to many things (e.g. what is movable, what not). Should study the BOM (bill of materials) to understand even how many motors, screws or meters of wires to buy. Not to find one late evening missing a rod, spring or nut. There is a lot of online sources to study to get an idea, try [reprap.org](https://reprap.org/wiki/Build_A_RepRap).

Comment: Best and cheapest solution IMHO is to get a kit, it has everything from frame to electronics. It is hard to beat the prices as the manufacturers get great deals on the specific parts when they buy in bulk.